# detect if inside a LaTeX ``quote'' and return its bounds?

Tags: latex, auctex

**Q:** how can I test if point is inside LaTeX ``quotes,'' and how can I get the bounds of that quote?

LaTeX quotation marks are kooky, typesetting ``text inside a double-quote'' and `text inside a single-quote' for the standard "text inside a double-quote" and 'text inside a single-quote'.

I'd like to detect if point is inside such a quote (either single or double) and, ideally, return the bounds of the quoted passage.   However, `syntax-ppss` does not appear to recognize such passages as strings (re: elements 3 and 8 in the returned list; see `parse-partial-sexp` for details).

Is there a predicate function baked-in to AUCTeX to do so?  Many of their functions also have   curious naming conventions, so I may have missed it.  If no such function already exists, what alternatives would work?

Comment: Similar to the answer of @abo-abo if you evaluate `(font-latex-faces-present-p '(font-latex-string-face))` inside a double quotation, you get true, otherwise false.

Answer (score 3):

You need this:

```
(defun latex-quote-bnd ()
  (save-excursion
    (beginning-of-line)
    (when (font-latex-match-quotation
           (line-end-position))
      (cons
       (match-beginning 0)
       (match-end 0)))))
```

I found `font-latex-match-quotation` simply by following `describe-face`.

Comment: Thanks for the find.  So far, though, it's a partial solution: it doesn't work for `single quotes', and it doesn't work for multi-line passages when point is not on the line with the opening ``.

Comment: In addition font-locking is lazy, in the sense that a not already visited region has no font face, so looking at it is pretty useless in that case.

Comment: It'd be more robust to just search for the quotes around point, and check that they're valid.

Comment: @Malabarba, I didn't even know about those type of quotes in LaTeX. Hence, just providing a proof-of-concept as a starting point, not trying to solve the whole thing.

Comment: @abo-abo Sure. Just trying to help. ;-)